# Find the last entry of a year and get adjacent value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image: Loan Data]

I would like a method to search through Column A and find the last entry of the year marked in K3 (2030), and display the corresponding Balance from Column H.

Problems I'm having:

1. Making the Vlookup search for the year in the date column
2. Finding the LAST entry for that year in the date column

Here is a link to the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13xhlfcV7KsRr3ObH5z1fxYUEMt8c6jssjlIozHk1MCI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Trashing your sheet will make this question useless to future Stack users. Maybe consider leaving it up as view only?

Comment: Restored the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

`=VLOOKUP(TO_DATE(LARGE(FILTER($A:$A,YEAR($A:$A)=$K$3),1)),$A:$H,8,FALSE)`